# How to implement Custom Ajax Multiple File Upload Javascript in Success.phtml page?

Tags: magento, file-upload

I want like after placing an order in MAGENTO...that is in `success.phtml` file...I want to give multiple file upload functionality. I am using uploadify script. I placed 2 js files & a small script & html code.

Now the thing is php file for uploading is not getting executed. Here is the code, I have put in success.phtml file :-

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"     type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://rootofsite/uploadify/jquery.uploadify.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://rootofsite/uploadify/uploadify.css">

<form>
    <div id="queue"></div>
    <input id="file_upload" name="file_upload" type="file" multiple="true">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    <?php $timestamp = time();?>
            var d = jQuery.noConflict();
    d(function() {
        d('#file_upload').uploadify({
            'formData'     : {
                'timestamp' : '<?php echo $timestamp;?>',
                'token'     : '<?php echo md5('unique_salt' . $timestamp);?>'
            },
            'swf'      : 'http://rootofsite/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
            'uploader' : 'http://rootofsite/uploadify/uploadify.php'
        });
    });
</script>
```

I have put uploadify(which contains all the things) folder in root. All going good but uploadify.php file is not getting executed.

Here is the demo link :- http://www.uploadify.com/demos/

As in the demo multiple files are being shown to be uploaded but actually not being uploaded :) because in my case uploadify.php is not getting executed. No javascript error nothing :) I do not want to make a module for it.

Any idea what's the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I should start by saying any Javascript really should be added via local.xml file and referenced in your themes skin folder.  Secondly, if you inspect the source of the page do you see your javascript?   A few things could be happening. You may be within the wrong folder structure of the success page,  you could have multiple instances of jquery running on the page or a couple others.    Maybe the dom isn't ready try this.

```
<script src="http://rootofsite/uploadify/jquery.uploadify.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://rootofsite/uploadify/uploadify.css">

<form>
    <div id="queue"></div>
    <input id="file_upload" name="file_upload" type="file" multiple="true">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    <?php $timestamp = time();?>
            var d = jQuery.noConflict();
    d(document).ready(function() {
        d(function() {
            d('#file_upload').uploadify({
                'formData'     : {
                    'timestamp' : '<?php echo $timestamp;?>',
                    'token'     : '<?php echo md5('unique_salt' . $timestamp);?>'
                },
                'swf'      : 'http://rootofsite/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
                'uploader' : 'http://rootofsite/uploadify/uploadify.php'
    }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Rob, now the thing is I checked the source & all good. Yes JS is coming so any suggestion? Please :)

Comment: Hello? Can anyone answer this please if you know how to do this?

Comment: Thanks Rob but the thing is it is still not getting uploaded. It shows the progress for uploading but actually nothing getting uploaded. Rob I just want to ask one thing that instead of going in uploadify.php can't we do it in this file itself? or can you suggest any other scipt. Actually I found it very simple to be used :) so I am using it but not uploading :(

Comment: Is there anyone knowing how to do this? What may be the wrong?